# Identify string values in between a text

Tags: python

I have the following `['You and i','everyone else','cat and dog','We u all']`

I need to somehow identify the strings next to `and` and `u`.

For example, i expect the following output:

> You
>
> i
>
> cat
>
> Dog
>
> We
>
> all

Basically, each sentence should split from `and` and `u`. I need the two text on either side of `and` and `u` to be printed.

What i did is wrong, but here is one of my attempts:

```
sen = [w for w in words if re.search(r'.*and*.','.*u*.', w)]
for st in sen:
    print st
```

Comment: Note your call to re.search - it doesn't take a comma separated list of things to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> import re
>>> words = ['You and i', 'everyone else', 'cat and dog', 'We u all']
>>> res = [re.search(r'(.*?) (and|u) (.*?)$', word) for word in words]
>>> for i in res:
...     if i is not None:
...             print i.group(1)
...             print i.group(3)
... 
You
i
cat
dog
We
all
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over every line. Detect if it has `and` or `u`. If yes then split it on that token and finally print. For all other lines ignore.

```
>>> sentences = ['You and i', 'everyone else', 'cat and dog', 'We u all']
>>> for line in sentences:
...     if 'and' in line:
...         for split_word in line.split('and'):
...             print split_word.strip()
...     elif ' u ' in line:
...         for split_word in line.split(' u '):
...             print split_word.strip()
...     else:
...         pass
... 
You
i
cat
dog
We
all
>>>
```

Comment: What should `['and and']` come out as ?

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['You and i','everyone else','cat and dog','We u all']

# Iterate.
for i in l:
    words = None

    # Split.
    if ' and ' in i:
        words = i.split(' and ')
    elif ' u ' in i:
        words = i.split(' u ')

    # Print.
    if words:
        for word in words:
            print word
```

Result:

```
You
i
cat
dog
We
all
```